# Big O of Expression Evaluation

Tags: big-o

I'm a teacher and told my students that the Big O of an expression such as y=15x+8 is O(1), however when we learned prefix and postfix, we discussed that evaluating these expressions is O(N) because you have to go through each character of the equation (assuming you're given a string).

One student asked how we said that evaluating an expression is O(1) if behind the scenes there must be either an infix, postfix or prefix evaluation being done.

I'm not sure what to answer.

Comment: It should be linear to the number of arithmetic operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *expression* does not have any time complexity as such. An *algorithm* to solve a *problem* can have a time complexity. So it all depends on what you define as your problem and what you define to be relevant parameters of complexity. If you have a *fixed* assignment such as

```
y := 15 * x + 8;
```

the *problem* can be defined as "compute the value of `15 * x + 8`, with input parameter `x`". So here you want to express time complexity as a function dependent on `x`. The time complexity is O(1), assuming we are talking about standard 32/64-bit arithmetic computations and otherwise `O(log x)`, if this is arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

However, if you regard the size of the expression as variable, the problem becomes "compute the value of an arithmetic expression tree with `k` nodes, where `k` is an input parameter". This is a *different* problem, and has a different complexity, as you correctly pointed out.